# Siliverlight 3 Navigation between user controls?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, navigation

Im just starting to get to grips with silverlight 3, coming from ASP.NET and Flex.

I have followed the new navigation tutorial [here](http://silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/navigation-framework/) and read through the authentication and role management tutorials also.

So, i have a main page, which has a frame, inside of the grid, and several views. These are all navigatable and working fine. I see this main page as kind of a master page to my little application i have i mind.

So know I want to have a login.xaml UserControl. This will handle all login and once authenticated I want to navigate to the MainPage, and the use its frame to go from there.

I dont just want to simply use login as a seprate page within my frame as I want the login to use a different grid to the rest of the app, and also to be separate.

So how would I navigate from one user control (Login) to another (Main) ?

I have tried

```
 private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //TO - DO: All the auth work, just want navigation sorted first

        this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        App.Current.RootVisual = new MainPage(); 
    }
```

With no luck. Ive also tried just init'n a new main and setting its Visibility but this of course doesnt work.

Am I even approaching this in the correct way?

Thanks muchly.

Edit - Ok after digging a little further, [this](http://craign.net/2008/03/11/how-to-switch-silverlight-usercontrols/) looks like an approach that will do what im after, but it does feel a little hackish! Is this the suggested way for siverlight 3? Thanks Again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I've usually done is to create a "MainPage.xaml" which is of type System.Windows.Controls.Navigation.  That gets assigned to the RootVisual property of my application; it's pretty much empty, except for a navigation frame:

```
<navigation:Page 
x:Class="Client.MainPage" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
mc:Ignorable="d" 
d:DesignWidth="400" 
d:DesignHeight="400" MinWidth="700" MinHeight="480"
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
Title="Main SlideLinc Page">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <navigation:Frame x:Name="rootFrame" />
</Grid>
</navigation:Page>
```

Then I use the "rootFrame" navigation frame to handle all my navigation needs, e.g., with these methods from a static NavigationManager class:

```
    public static void Navigate(string url, Action<Exception, UIElement> callback)
    {
        Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), callback);
    }

    public static void Navigate(Uri uri, Action<Exception, UIElement> callback)
    {
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            Logger.LogMessage("Can't use navigation, because rootFrame is null");
            ErrorMessageBox.Show(ClientStrings.NavigationFailed);
        }
        else
        {
            NavigatedEventHandler successHandler = null;
            NavigationFailedEventHandler failureHandler = null;
            successHandler = (s, e) =>
                 {
                     rootFrame.Navigated -= successHandler;
                     rootFrame.NavigationFailed -= failureHandler;
                     if (callback != null)
                     {
                         callback(null, e.Content as UIElement);
                     }
                 };
            failureHandler = (s, e) =>
                {
                    rootFrame.Navigated -= successHandler;
                    rootFrame.NavigationFailed -= failureHandler;
                    if (callback != null)
                    {
                        callback(e.Exception, null);
                    }
                };
            rootFrame.Navigated += successHandler;
            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += failureHandler;
            rootFrame.Navigate(uri);
        }
    }
```

So in your case, you might use it like:

```
NavigationManager.Navigate(new Uri("/Login.xaml", UriKind.Relative), null);
```

Or:

```
NavigationManager.Navigate(new Uri("/Home.xaml", UriKind.Relative), (error, element) => InitializeElement(element));
```

Comment: This a great approach, nice and clean.

Thanks Ken

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 types of containers in SL3

1. Pages (Views)
2. UserControls
3. ChildWindows (Popups)

Do not swap UserControls, its a bad idea, it basically means clearing the "MainPage" content and Adding a new UserControl. By doing ths you lose the Back/Forth behavior of the browser since the URL never changes, thats not how the Navigation Framework was designed, you rather swap Pages (views) do this by using the NavigationService.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //TO - DO: All the auth work, just want navigation sorted first

        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/HomePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Now HomePage.xaml is a Page (not a UserControl), on Startup your default load page for the NavigationFrame should be your login page.

UserControls are meant to be re-usable functionality that can be deployed on multiple pages.